# Can't install rtracklayer on CentOS 7 and R 4

Tags: r, installation, centos, centos7, bioconductor

I have tried installing the `rtracklayer` package using Bioconductor on R 4.0.2 and CentOS 7 without success. This is the error that I get:

```
installing to ~/bin/R/lib64/R/library/00LOCK-rtracklayer/00new/rtracklayer/libs
** R
** data
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Creating a generic function for ‘offset’ from package ‘stats’ in package ‘rtracklayer’
Creating a generic function from function ‘uri’ in package ‘rtracklayer’
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rtracklayer’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '~/bin/R/lib64/R/library/00LOCK-rtracklayer/00new/rtracklayer/libs/rtracklayer.so':
  ~/bin/R/lib64/R/library/00LOCK-rtracklayer/00new/rtracklayer/libs/rtracklayer.so: undefined symbol: CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘~/bin/R/lib64/R/library/rtracklayer’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmpet2cyn/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘rtracklayer’ had non-zero exit status
```

I haven't been able to fix this. Note: I've changed the absolute address of my home folder to "~"

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/115732/. Bottom line, it might be a version discrepancy in openssl headers and link libraries. Or just an incorrect version overall. (Sorry, I don't centos, just a pointer.)

Comment: Thanks. However, my error seems to be related to something different. Specifically because of this line `undefined symbol: CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
Error: loading failed`. I haven't been able to address that

Comment: Yes ... and `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback` is a symbol exported by OpenSSL.

Comment: Oh I see. I tried the solution on the linked resource but unfortunately it didn't work. The env variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` wasn't specified in my case so I fixed that, but it still throws the same error